# Why iterator is not fetching the remaining objects?

Tags: java, collections, tree, treeset

I am trying to understand the tree set .
Why below code is only printing

> a not b and c.

Below is the code:

```
Set<Person> tr = new TreeSet<Person>();

    tr.add(new Person("a",1));
        tr.add(new Person("c",7));
        tr.add(new Person("5",5));

        Iterator itr = tr.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {

            Person person = (Person) itr.next();
            System.out.println(person.getName());
        }
```

Person Class

```
package com.set;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String name;

    private int age;


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Person(String name , int age) {
        this.name= name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {

            if(age > o.getAge() )
            {
                return 0;
            }else{
                return 1;
            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Show us your Person's hashcode and equals method

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your Person class. Can you share that also?

Comment: Have you overloaded `equals()`/`compareTo()` in `Person`?

Comment: @Juned Added person class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting by age you need to take in account the both directions it can differ. Also, to keep `compareTo()` consistent with equals you should take in account the names too, if the ages are same.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {
    int ret = age - o.getAge();
    if (ref == 0) {
        return name.compareTo(o.getName());
    }
    return ret;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Person) {
        Person p = (Person) o;
        return p.getAge() == age && p.getName().equals(name);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return 0 from your compareTo() only if age of both objects is equal

@Override

public int compareTo(Person o) {

```
    if(age == o.getAge() )
    {
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
```

}

Comment: It would have given exception if I have not written code to compareTO method.

Comment: @Thinker I mean the default compareTo() implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct code. To use a `TreeSet` your `Person` class has to implement the `Comparable` interface (it will not compile otherwise). If your code is not printing all the elements, it means, that you have implemented the `compareTo` method in a way, that all there `Person` objects are treated as one, so

```
 (new Person("a",1)).compareTo(new Person("c",7)) == 0
 (new Person("a",1)).compareTo(new Person("5",5)) == 0
```

if for example, you would like `Person` to be identified by their name (String object), this could be written as

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    String name;
    int age;
    private Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

which prints out

```
5
a
c
```

if you would like whole data pair to be used as an identifier, then it would be more reasonable to use `HashSet` (as it requires only to define when objects are equal, while `TreeSet` as an ordered data structure requires some kind of ordering, that you declare with `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your compareTo method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {

        if(age > o.getAge() )
        {
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }

}
```

TreeSet uses compareTo() used to decide the equality of objects. And your implementation of compareTo will return 0 in all the cases when the new object age is greater than the existing element.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `comapreTo` method ,modify like this

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {

    if(age == o.getAge() )
    {
        return 0;
    }else if(age>o.getAge(){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

according to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29)

> comapreTo() method Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.